# What does MVC Even mean in the context of IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, model-view-controller

I used to have a massive packed 8k+ line FeedViewController and anytime I wanted to change anything involving the look of statuses I had to change no less than a dozen viewcontrllers so I decided to try to refactor to follow a MVC type standard. I put most of the functionality in the tableviewcells so that I could just change the cell class instead of 12 files, now im hearing "you should keep your VIEWS dumb.....is this really so wrong?

```
//
//  TriCornerFeedCell.m

//

//
#import "NSDate+TimeAgo.h"
#import "TriCornerFeedCell.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"


@implementation TriCornerFeedCell

-(void)refreshGestureRecognizers{

    while (self.gestureRecognizers.count) {
        [self removeGestureRecognizer:[self.gestureRecognizers objectAtIndex:0]];
    }
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(processDoubleTap:)];
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1.3; //seconds
    lpgr.delegate = self;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
}




-(void)refreshCell{

     _sdmanager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];


//Set Name Label
    self.NameLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",self.statusObject.first_name,self.statusObject.last_name];

//Set Message Label
    if(self.statusObject.message!=nil){
        self.StatusLabel.enabledTextCheckingTypes = NSTextCheckingTypeLink;
        self.StatusLabel.text = self.statusObject.message;
        self.StatusLabel.delegate = self;
        [self checkForShoutoutsAndHashtags];
        self.StatusLabel.lineBreakMode=0;
        self.StatusLabel.numberOfLines=0;
        //Cell.StatusLabel.text=[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"message"];
        [self.StatusLabel sizeToFit];

    }

//Set Date Label
    NSDate *date = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeIntervalSince1970:self.statusObject.created];
    self.timeLabel.text=[date timeAgo];

//Set Bump Views
    if(self.statusObject.isBumped){
         [self.bumpCornerBG setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"corner_bump_yellow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }else{
        [self.bumpCornerBG setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"corner_bump_grey.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    self.bumpCount.text=[@(self.statusObject.bump_count) stringValue];
    [self.bumpClearViewBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(bump:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.bumpCornerBG addTarget:self action:@selector(bump:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


//Set Comment Related Views


    if(self.statusObject.comment_count>0){
        NSLog(@"COMMENT_COUNT:%d",self.statusObject.comment_count);
        [self.commentCount setHidden:NO];
        [self.miniCommentColorCircle setHidden:NO];
        self.commentCount.text=[@(self.statusObject.comment_count) stringValue];
    }else{
        [self.commentCount setHidden:YES];
        [self.miniCommentColorCircle setHidden:YES];
    }

//Set Follow Btn Views
    [self.followBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"BloggerSans" size:14]];
    [self.followBtn removeFromSuperview];
    if(!self.statusObject.isFollowing){

        [self.followBtn removeFromSuperview];
        UIButton *followBtn= [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(235, 16, 75, 25)];
        [followBtn setImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        followBtn.layer.cornerRadius =2; // this value vary as per your desire
        [followBtn.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"BloggerSans" size:14.0f]];
        followBtn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(3, 0, 0, 0);
        followBtn.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [followBtn setTitleColor:[self colorWithHexString:@"ff68a8"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        followBtn.layer.borderWidth=1.5f;
        followBtn.layer.borderColor=[[self colorWithHexString:@"ff68a8"] CGColor];
        [followBtn setTitle:@"Follow" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [followBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(follow) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        self.followBtn=followBtn;
        [self addSubview:self.followBtn];

    }


//Reset icon to default in case default==nill
    [self bringSubviewToFront:self.DefaultImgBorder];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:self.DefaultImgBtn];
    UIImage *noDefault = [UIImage imageNamed:@"female_mini_no_default_icon.png"];
    [self.DefaultImgBtn setBackgroundImage:noDefault forState:UIControlStateNormal];

//Attempt to create hexagon cropped default photo
    UIImage *hex_img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"big_hex_thumb.png"];
    UIImage *tan=[UIImage imageNamed:@"feed_grey.png"];
    UIImage *finalBG= [self maskImage:tan withMask:hex_img];
    [self.DefaultImgBorder setImage:finalBG];
    NSURL *thumb_url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",s3thumbURL,self.statusObject.thumb_img]];
    @autoreleasepool {
        [_sdmanager downloadWithURL:thumb_url
                            options:0
                           progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize){}completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished){
             if (image)
             {
                 UIImage *thumbimg = image;
                 UIImage *hex_img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"big_hex_thumb.png"];
                 UIImage *noDefault = [UIImage imageNamed:@"female_mini_no_default_icon.png"];
                 [self.DefaultImgBtn setBackgroundImage:noDefault forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                 UIImage *finalImg= [self maskImage:thumbimg withMask:hex_img];
                 [self.DefaultImgBtn setBackgroundImage:finalImg forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
             }
         }];
    }
    [self.DefaultImgBtn removeTarget:nil
                              action:NULL
                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
    [self.DefaultImgBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(viewProfile:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


//Misc Stuff
    [self setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

}

#pragma mark - Interaction Methods

-(void)follow{


    [self.followSpinner removeFromSuperview];
    [self.followBtn removeFromSuperview];
    self.followSpinner = [[RTSpinKitView alloc] initWithStyle:RTSpinKitViewStyleFadingCircleAlt color: [self colorWithHexString:@"b4b4b2"] spinnerSize:25];
    [self.followSpinner setFrame:CGRectMake(260,15,30,30)];
    self.spinner.tag=9;
    [self addSubview:self.followSpinner];
    [self.statusObject follow];
}
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

    if (self.indexPath != nil && gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {


        NSString*loggedin_uid = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"uid"];


        if([self.statusObject.IMPORT_SOURCE isEqualToString:@"INSTAGRAM"] || [self.statusObject.IMPORT_SOURCE isEqualToString:@"TWITTER"]){

            if([loggedin_uid isEqualToString:@"1"] || [loggedin_uid isEqualToString:@"2"]){

                [self.delegate showImportAdminControls:self.indexPath];
            }

        }else{

            if([loggedin_uid isEqualToString:@"1"] || [loggedin_uid isEqualToString:@"2"]){

                [self.delegate showAdminControls:self.indexPath];

            }else if ([self.statusObject.uid isEqualToString:loggedin_uid]){

                [self.delegate deletePostAlert:self.indexPath];

            }
        }

    }
}
- (void) processDoubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{


    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        if (self.indexPath)
        {
            self.statusObject.indexPath=self.indexPath;

            if(!self.statusObject.isBumped){


                int value = self.statusObject.bump_count+1;
                self.statusObject.isBumped=YES;
                self.statusObject.bump_count=value;
                [self.bumpCount setText:[@(value) stringValue]];
                [self.bumpCornerBG setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"corner_bump_yellow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                UIImageView *bumpBlowUpIcon=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width/2)-5, (self.frame.size.height/2)-5, 10, 10)];
                [bumpBlowUpIcon setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart_yellow.png"]];
                bumpBlowUpIcon.alpha=.2;
                [self addSubview:bumpBlowUpIcon];

                [UIView animateWithDuration:.8 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:.3 initialSpringVelocity:.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

                    [bumpBlowUpIcon setFrame:CGRectMake((self.frame.size.width/2)-(self.frame.size.height/2), 0, self.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.height)];
                    bumpBlowUpIcon.alpha=.5;

                }completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                    [bumpBlowUpIcon removeFromSuperview];
                }];


            }else{

                int value = self.statusObject.bump_count-1;
                self.statusObject.isBumped=NO;
                self.statusObject.bump_count=value;
                [self.bumpCount setText:[@(value) stringValue]];
                [self.bumpCornerBG setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"corner_bump_grey.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }



            [self.statusObject bump];





        }
    }

}




-(void)viewProfile{



}

-(void)viewHashtag{



}



#pragma mark - Misc Methods




- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *) image withMask:(UIImage *) mask
{
    CGImageRef imageReference = image.CGImage;
    CGImageRef maskReference = mask.CGImage;

    CGImageRef imageMask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskReference),
                                             CGImageGetHeight(maskReference),
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskReference),
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskReference),
                                             CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskReference),
                                             CGImageGetDataProvider(maskReference),
                                             NULL, // Decode is null
                                             YES // Should interpolate
                                             );

    CGImageRef maskedReference = CGImageCreateWithMask(imageReference, imageMask);
    CGImageRelease(imageMask);

    UIImage *maskedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:maskedReference];
    CGImageRelease(maskedReference);

    return maskedImage;
}

-(UIColor*)colorWithHexString:(NSString*)hex
{
    NSString *cString = [[hex stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] uppercaseString];

    // String should be 6 or 8 characters
    if ([cString length] < 6) return [UIColor grayColor];

    // strip 0X if it appears
    if ([cString hasPrefix:@"0X"]) cString = [cString substringFromIndex:2];

    if ([cString length] != 6) return  [UIColor grayColor];

    // Separate into r, g, b substrings
    NSRange range;
    range.location = 0;
    range.length = 2;
    NSString *rString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

    range.location = 2;
    NSString *gString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

    range.location = 4;
    NSString *bString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

    // Scan values
    unsigned int r, g, b;
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:rString] scanHexInt:&r];
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:gString] scanHexInt:&g];
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:bString] scanHexInt:&b];

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((float) r / 255.0f)
                           green:((float) g / 255.0f)
                            blue:((float) b / 255.0f)
                           alpha:1.0f];
}

@end
```

Comment: When you want to stick to the MVC pattern you should keep your views as dumb as possible, that's correct. In the best case they should not contain any business logic.

Comment: Please read I asked a more specific Q that puts that theory in question

Comment: "... not contain any business logic" implies that they also should **not** know **anything** about business _objects_ (the model). As long as your `statusObject` in `self.StatusLabel.text = self.statusObject.message;` is anything else than a Data Transfer Object it is not a good idea to let the cells retrieve their values on their own.

Comment: Is this situational at all? bc your changes would literally mean x12 the extra code...i literally have 12 completely unique screens that display statuses in one way or another. If I can have a cell do all the work and change just one tableviewcell vs 12 viewcontrollers doesn't  common sense say my way makes sense?

Comment: You could compose your view controllers with functionality they need. For example: if some views need data from somewhere you could introduce a separate (view related) component which will provide that data (e.g. by returning cells). This component could be used by all view controllers who need those information.

Comment: The idea of thinking of how that would work makes my head hurt a bit, one is a profile, one is a feed of recent friend activity , one is a search view controller, one appears when you long press on a tinder like card displaying the last few statuses by that user and i mean does it not feel x10 as complex trying to just remember that all these phantom methods are there....idk im not trying to fight the right way, but it just feels like there should be exceptions.

Comment: You are always allowed to do make exceptions ;-) It's often a compromise between how strict you follow a pattern and what suits your needs (especially for projects that are not being developed from scratch but shall be refactored).

Comment: I just ran into the reason why your solution starts to make sense....I have multiple types of model objects and multiple types of cells, if i make say the photostatuscell  a subclass of this cell and give it a photoObject as a property it gets confusing fast. thank you for your feedback.

Comment: please leave a answer and I will accept

Comment: @ChuckKelly, the view-layer is view, it has to do what the view-layer has to do with its subview, layers etc..., it does not matter how complex is that; but it should not do any controller-layer stuff, if that is how you referred as _"keep it dumb"_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've tried to merge all comments to a suitable answer.

When you want to stick to the MVC pattern you should keep your views as dumb as possible (regarding the coupling of view- and business-related components). In the best case they should not contain any business logic. 
That implies that they also should not know anything about business *objects* (the model). As long as your `statusObject` in `self.StatusLabel.text = self.statusObject.message;` is anything else than a Data Transfer Object it is not a good idea to let the cells retrieve their values on their own - because then these cells would need to have knowledge about your model structure.

Usually each view does have its own view controller but - of course - you're allowed to compose your view controllers with functionality they need.

For example: if some view controllers need data you could introduce a separate (view related) component which will provide that data (e.g. by creating and returning cells). This component would be fed with your model data (or Data Transfer Objects) and would return a structure which could be used by all view controllers who need those information.